# Ideas needed for a project with a lot of buttons

Tags: microcontroller, led, button, ideas

Alright so this may sound very weird. Even though I'm 19 years old, I still like electronics with a lot of LEDs and buttons and pots and switches. You know what I'm talking about.
I saw this video on YouTube by Make https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j6zseFi070E
The guy builds a mission control desk for his kid(best dad ever). Of course that would be a little too impractical for my age but I'm looking for something with that many things on the top.
Any ideas?
I want the following things to be included:

1. LEDs
2. LED bargraphs
3. LED seven seg displays
4. Buttons
5. Switches
6. Toggle switches
7. Illuminated switches
8. Keys

Everything you can think of basically.
I'm looking to build it myself.
Any and every idea is helpful
Help :)

Comment: This question isn't a good fit for this site. I suggest you refine it if you have a specific engineering question. Otherwise it is likely to be closed as too broad.

Comment: Ok what if I wanted to make a modular system of LFO and HFOs so I could control each one individually and/or chain them together to achieve different waveforms. Any suggestions on that?

Comment: That's just a different question, not a better one...

Comment: "`You know what I'm talking about...`" No... not really. The video you have provided LITERALLY shows you how all the lights are turning on and off and how the seven segment displays work. Why are you limiting yourself by your age? I'm almost 24 but I know multiple programming languages, work for one of the largest companies in the world, pursuing a Master's in Electrical Engineering, and a contributing member of IEEE. Why would you make an assumption that something is impractical all because of your age? It's good to show some humility but don't limit yourself of what you can and can't do :)

Answer (score 3):

As professional EEs we try and minimize all of the above, because every switch and LED means custom enclosure mods, and that means money. However, maybe get something like an old slow 8 bit CPU where address and data busses come out and do an old style Altair 8080 type bootup interface
[image]

Comment: As an old EE I recall how exciting it was to be able to own a Real Computer - 8 bits, 4MHz. I doubt those days will be here again, unless homebrew Quantum Computing arrives. Not so much fun these days despite working with machines a million times more powerful.

Comment: Wow looks cool ...

Comment: Not as cool as the pink and purple PDP-11 consoles with piano key switches. Now that would be a nice project!